# How do I get my UITextView to be centered and to be sized to fit the text it contains and not hardcoded?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview

I have a UIViewController with a UITextView, a UIImage, and three UILabels, it looks like this when I run it on the iOS simulator:

[image: Portrait UIViewController rendering]

But when I flip it to landscape the central UITextView shrinks vertically so much so that the text isn't even visible anymore:

[image: Landscape UIViewController rendering]

The UIImage is hidden and sits on top of the UITextView, it doesn't warp when I rotate to landscape. The current constraints on the UITextView are:

```
Align Center Y to: Superview
Align Center X to: the UIImage
Top Space to image: Default
Width Equals 250
```

I have tried tweaking the hugging and compression priorities to no avail. My theory was that the lack of a Height constraint causes this, and, indeed when I set a Height Constraint of 250 I don't see it shrink (but it doesn't feel like the right thing to do). What constraint do I need in order to have it simply size itself according to the text it contains?

In response to comments below, my constraints are as follows:

On the UIImageView at the top center:

```
1.) Align Center X to SuperView
2.) Align Center X to Text View = 4
3.) Top Space to Top Layout = 15
4.) Bottom Space to Text View = Default
```

On the Text View which I want below it:

```
1.) Align Center Y to SuperView
2.) Width Equals: 250
3.) Align Center X to Image 
4.) Top Space to Image
```

On the leftmost label below I have:

```
1.) Leading Space to Superview = 45
2.) Trailing Space to Center Label
3.) Align Center Y to rightmost label
4.) Bottom Space to Bottom Layout
```

On the hidden center label im using to create some space between the two displayed labels:

```
1.) Align Center X to SuperView
2.) Trailing Space to rightmost label = Default
3.) Align Center Y to leftmost label
4.) Align Center Y to rightmost label
5.) Bottom Space to Bottom Label = 8
6.) Equal height to rightmost label
```

Finally, on the rightmost label I have:

```
1.) Trailing Space to Superview = 45
2.) Leading Space to center hidden label = default
3.) Align Center Y to leftmost label
4.) Align Center Y to center hidden label
5.) Bottom Space to Bottom Layout = Default
6.) Equal Height to center hidden Label
```

What I really want to fix is the text view "hugging" it's content and expanding freely down as much as needed to hold the text. But tweaking hugging/compression priorities does not seem to do it and it is shrinking when I flip it as below..

Comment: Seems like you have more constraints, or hardcoded values, than you tell us here. Otherwise how does the portrait view have a larger box than it's actual content? Have you constrained the inner content of your "orange box"?

Comment: It looks to me like you also have a constraint between your text view and either the bottom of the view, or one of the labels.

Comment: @rdelmar I added the constraints in an edit above, im not sure how to achieve the hugging but expand freely downwards effect for the textview

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I added all the constraints I see above. I'm still playing around with them to see if I can avoid the shrinking of the text view

Comment: Do you have scrolling enabled or disabled on the text view?